# Batch Script adding a command to know when process is done

Tags: batch-file, process, wait

I am running a script and it uses psexec to run a batch on a remote pc.
When it runs that batch, it is running silent and there is no output to see when it is complete.
It can run 3 minutes or an hour.

Is there anything that can be added to have it either wait till complete or notify me when done?

Here is my script.

```
@echo off
REM FIREFOX
Robocopy "%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox" "c:\temp\browser_backup\FFini" *.* /e /R:3
Robocopy "%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" "c:\temp\browser_backup\Firefox_Profile\Default" *.* /e /R:3

@echo off
REM CHROME
Robocopy "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" "c:\temp\browser_backup\Chrome" *.* /e /R:3 /xjd

@echo off
REM IE
Robocopy "c:\Users\%username%\Favorites" "c:\temp\browser_backup\Favorites" *.* /e /R:3

@echo off
REM EDGE
echo F | xcopy "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks" "c:\temp\browser_backup\Edge Favorites\bookmarks"
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: My first advice is to change ```C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local``` to ```%LocalAppData%```.

Comment: Please also remove all of those additional ```@echo off``` lines. You turned it off once at the top, and nothing has turned it on again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
echo I'm finished>tempfilename.txt
notepad filename.txt
```